# Which version of NFS is my NFS server using?

Tags: configuration, nfs, version

I'm mounting a NFS filesystem on my machine.  How do I figure out what version of the NFS protocol the server uses?  I don't have access to the NFS server machine, but I do have root on my client machine.

Is there anything I can run on my client machine to identify what version of the NFS protocol is being used by the server, or what versions it supports?

I wasn't able to find any useful information in `/var/log/messages` or kernel debugging output (`dmesg`).

I have tried running `nfsstat`, but I'm not sure if it is giving me any useful information.  However, when I run `nfsstat -s` to request information about the server, I don't see anything useful:

```
# nfsstat -s
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
0          0          0          0          0
```

When I run `nfsstat -c` to request information about the client, I do see some information about `Client nfs v3`, but I'm not sure how to interpret this.  Does this tell me anything about the protocol being used between my client machine and the NFS server?  Does it mean I am currently using v3 of the NFS protocol?  Does it tell me anything about what versions of the NFS protocol the server supports, e.g., NFS v4?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `nfsstat -c` program will show you the NFS version actually being used.

If you run `rpcinfo -p {server}` you will see all the versions of all the RPC programs that the *server* supports. On my system I get this output:

```
$ rpcinfo -p localhost
   program vers proto   port
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    ...
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    ...
```

This shows me that my NFS server (`localhost` in this example) offers versions 2, 3, and 4 of the NFS protocol all over UDP and TCP.

Comment: How can you tell if V4 is 4.2 or something else (preferably without having the nfs actually running .. as I cannot mount from the client for some reason)?

Comment: @Dylan why not ask that as a new question?

Comment: I do not understand why one should ask a new question to get more details on the same answer!

Comment: @Madhusoodan because I don't know the answer to that part

Comment: Ok :) I will ask new one! @roaima

Comment: On the NFS server side, cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions can be used to see the specific version (4, 4.1, 4.2) it exports.

Answer (score 7):

Depending your OS and version there may be different ways to check it.

nfsstat:

```
# nfsstat -m
/mnt/share from 10.0.0.1:/mnt/share
Flags:  rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.0.0.1,mountvers=3,mountport=30924,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.1
```

But you can for sure

```
# grep nfs /proc/mounts
10.0.0.1:/mnt/share /mnt/share nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.0.0.1,mountvers=3,mountport=30924,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.1
```

which is obviously the same output.

It shows `vers=3` on server, and `mountvers=3`.

Comment: `grep nfs /proc/mounts` (for me on the server) only displays `nfsd /proc/nfsd nfsd rw,realtime 0 0`. I don't have the client actually mounted (I can't get it to work). Everything seems fine (using nfs4 on both, IP addresses are correct, /etc/exports is fine, `nfs-server` has been restarted, `exportfs -rav` looks fine, `showmount -e server` from client looks fine, etc. .. but when I try to mount *EVERY TIME* .. it hangs until `mount.nfs: Connection timed out` --or-- `mount.nfs4: Connection timed out`. So frustrating. Sorry for my rant that will probably go unfixed).

Comment: so, I guess .. is there a way to get the nfs version (like 4.2 or 4.1 or what have you) without having the client mounted?

Comment: I have been working hard on the same issue. All is fine and it used to work. I recreated my Vagrant VM's and then it stopped working. Nfsstat shows that all calls are badcalls of typ badauth.

Comment: @Dylan, the server is configured to operate w/multiple versions of NFS.  Depending on the server configuration and/or the client abilities/configs, there are multiple possible answers.  Furthermore, if you don't have any clients connecting to the nfs server, you can check your server config files and/or `/proc/fs/nfsd/versions` to find out what versions the server is configured to support.

Answer (score -3):

One can open `/etc/nfsmount.conf` and get the information about default version and supported version.