# Accessing a legacy NFS

Tags: nfs

I have an old headless box running Caldera Linux from 1990s. There is no SSH in Caldera. The box has no USB or other ways to add a portable drive.  Years ago, I had similar Linux boxes and I used NFS to back up. My other boxes have become more modern and I have not made a back up of the Caldera box in years. I'm feeling a bit insecure. Via telnet, I use the box regularly and add data.

I was considering pulling the drives out temporarily and turning them into USB drives. But, right now, I'm trying NFS again. Over the years, I've tried to mount the Caldera on a more modern Debian/Ubuntu/Mint box. In every case, I've failed and put the project aside as not urgent.

I've just done done a fresh Mint 19 install just to pursue this problem.  For naught:

```
root@willie-Latitude-E6420:/mnt# mount -t nfs 192.168.110.16:/ /mnt/bookkeep
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
```

Can anyone offer any insight on the incompatibilities in NFS that have been introduced over the years as "improvements"? Can anyone suggest a distribution that might support old NFS mounts? Or other work arounds?

```
rpcinfo -p bookkeep
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    300019    1   udp    731  amd
    100005    1   udp    766  mountd
    100005    2   udp    766  mountd
    100005    1   tcp    769  mountd
    100005    2   tcp    769  mountd
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100001   13   udp    780  rstatd
    100001    3   udp    780  rstatd
    100001    2   udp    780  rstatd
    100001    1   udp    780  rstatd
    100001   13   tcp    785  rstatd
    100001    3   tcp    785  rstatd
    100001    2   tcp    785  rstatd
    100001    1   tcp    785  rstatd

rpcinfo -p localhost
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  53399  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  46155  mountd
    100005    2   udp  49673  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  47513  mountd
    100005    3   udp  42853  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  54595  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  34963  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  34963  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  34963  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  46437  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  46437  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  46437  nlockmgr
```

Comment: Start with [Which version of NFS is my NFS server using?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185831/100397)

Comment: I'm not sure of any version associated with NFS.  Here is /proc/version:Linux version 2.0.33 (root@buildmeister.caldera.com) (gcc version 2.7.2.3) #1 We
d Jan 7 09:11:54 MST 1998

Comment: You need to run the command given in the linked answer. Either from your client or the server - it doesn't really matter. In your case, you'd replace `{server}` with `192.168.110.16`

Comment: OK, I got the rpcinfo for both nfs server and client but am not allowed to copy into this comment'

Comment: Please update your question to include the new information. This isn't a forum so don't write "edit" or "update", but instead incorporate the information cleanly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `rpcinfo` output for the server, which I assume is `bookkeep`, you can see that NFS is only offered as version 2:

```
rpcinfo -p bookkeep
   program vers proto   port  service
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
```

Armed with this information we can attempt to force the client to fall back to that particular (ancient) version

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=2 bookkeep:/ /mnt/bookkeep
```

Comment: Words can not describe how thrilled I am.

Comment: The mount went smoothly, I'm now (slowly) backing up.

Comment: I guess I should attempt to pretty up the question so it might be of use to others?